# Will database in Amazon-RDS gets deleted if I click on Delete/Drop in PG admin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Could be a foolish question but just want to know,

I have connected to my Database in Amazon-RDS through PG Admin 4, if I right click on the servername and click on Delete/Drop. Will that delete database from RDS

[image: ma]

Comment: No, it will not be deleted as it is just the connection. if you delete the database which is inside it then it will be deleted from AWS

Comment: It will not be deleted